# Asp.net regex validator does not work

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

My textbox should contain 8 digits. If not i want to pop up an alert box. But the regualr expression validator does not trigger. Why?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkPayment" CssClass="btn mainBtn" runat="server" onclick="LinkPayment_Click" OnClientClick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/virtualgoal/smspayment']);">Betal ></asp:LinkButton>  

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredCustomersPhone" Display="None" ValidationGroup="ValGroupCustomersPhone" ControlToValidate="CustomersPhone" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Du må fylle inn ditt mobilnummer!"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>   

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegExValCustomersPhone" ValidationGroup="ValGroupCustomersPhone" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CustomersPhone" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Telefonnummer må bestå av 8 siffer!" ValidationExpression="[0-9]{8}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary" ShowSummary="False" ValidationGroup="ValGroupCustomersPhone" ShowMessageBox="True" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Does the `RequiredFieldValidator` trigger?

Comment: FYI, the first line of your markup is invalid (extra chevron before the closing `linkbutton` tag).

Comment: it triggers, but now i see that Page.IsValid returns true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following code:

```
ValidationGroup="ValGroupCustomersPhone"
```

to your linkbutton

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to validate an empty field? You may need a required field validatior as well. It's a shame there is no 'ValidateEmptyText' field on Regex validators.

Comment: there is a required field validatior!

Comment: @espvar Pardon me, Im being blind :)

Comment: Still fair suggestion though, it won't fire if its blank.

Comment: Ok, i see what you mean, and  I was testing it with content. To few/many digits and chars.